# How to share ebook creation troubleshooting tips

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Lately I've had several fairly arcane errors crop up while creating ebooks. I've troubleshot most of those, and would love to be able to share what I've learned with the community so that other people don't have to slog through the testing and whatnot that I have. The problem is, the two errors I'm thinking about don't seem to fit well into a Q&A format:

- The first issue was one where Kindle Previewer was throwing an undocumented error on ingesting an epub file. I was able to develop a workaround, but not to track down exactly what Previewer didn't like or what specific things would cause the error.
- The second issue was Kindle Previewer crashing occasionally when viewing a file. I was able to narrow the problem down to one particular font through testing, but again I have no idea why this particular font causes problems.

Both of these seem much more like tips than like Q&As—more like "Hey, here's something to check if you're having these kinds of problems" than like "here's how this works and why it's causing you problems." So is there a place for that kind of thing here, or in Stack Exchange sites in general, or are these the sorts of things I should just go write blog posts about?

Comment: If you can word these errors as objective questions, I see no reason not to post them.

Comment: I'm with @NathanOsman. Perhaps structure the questions as "what can I do if...?", "what should I check if...?" or something similar to make clear you don't have an ultimate fix so much as a method for isolating and working around the problems.